.ToList() taking too much time to convert
These are two quick queries that are not taking time to execute.
However, only one line takes longer than two to three minutes when I convert a query from AsQueryable to.ToList(). But I need the info within a second.
This is code. Please help me to solve this
var apiUser = ApiCall.InstanceAPIUser();
                var allusers = (await apiUser.UsersGetAllAsync()).Data.ToList();
                IQueryable<AllDocumentDetails> documents = null;
                var currentRut = allCompanies.FirstOrDefault().Rut;
                var documentsSql = acompDbContext.Documents.ToList();

                var rutList = allCompanies.Select(c => c.Rut).ToList();
                var query1 = from d1 in documentsSql
                             join c in rutList on d1.DocRecep equals c
                             join da in acompDbContext.DocumentAssignations on d1.DocumentId equals da.DocumentId
                             join dau in acompDbContext.DocumentAssignationAssignedUsers on da.DocumentAssignationId equals dau.DocumentAssignationId
                             join drp in acompDbContext.DocumentReceivedProcesses on d1.DocumentId equals drp.DocumentId into drpGroup
                             from drp in drpGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join dc in acompDbContext.DocumentComments on d1.DocumentId equals dc.DocumentId into dcGroup
                             from dc in dcGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             let assignedUser = acompDbContext.DocumentAssignationAssignedUsers
                                                  .Where(c => c.DocumentAssignationId == da.DocumentAssignationId && da.InProcess == true && d1.DocumentId == da.DocumentId)
                                                  .Select(x => x.UserId)
                                                  .Distinct()
                                                  .ToList()
                             select new AllDocumentDetails
                             {
                                 DocumentId = Convert.ToInt32(d1.DocumentId), // Include the unique identifier
                                 AssignedUser = allusers.Where(x => assignedUser.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => new AssignedUser { UserId = x.Id, Email = x.Email }).ToList(),
                                 DocumentType = d1.DocumentTypeId,
                                 DocSeries = d1.Serie,
                                 DocNumber = d1.Nro,
                                 DocRecep = d1.DocRecep,
                                 RutTaxId = d1.EmitingRUC,
                                 IssuedDate = d1.FchEmis,
                                 DueDate = d1.ExpireDate,
                                 CompanyName = d1.LegalName,
                                 ApprovalDate = drp.ExpiringApprovalDate,
                                 State = Convert.ToInt32(drp.Status),
                                 Claim = dc != null && dc.Claim == true,
                                 Comments = dc != null && dc.DocumentCommentId != 0,
                                 Pause = drp.Status.ToString() == "5",
                                 ApprovalType = Convert.ToInt32(da.ApprovalType),
                                 ExpiredApproval = drp.ExpiredApproval
                             };

                var query2 = from d1 in documentsSql
                             join c in rutList on d1.DocRecep equals c
                             join drp in acompDbContext.DocumentReceivedProcesses on d1.DocumentId equals drp.DocumentId into drpGroup
                             from drp in drpGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join dc in acompDbContext.DocumentComments on d1.DocumentId equals dc.DocumentId into dcGroup
                             from dc in dcGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where !acompDbContext.Documents
                                      .Any(d =>
                                          d.DocumentId == d1.DocumentId &&
                                          rutList.Contains(d.DocRecep) &&
                                          d.DocumentAssignations != null &&
                                          d.DocumentAssignations.Any(da => da.DocumentId == d.DocumentId))
                             select new AllDocumentDetails
                             {
                                 DocumentId = Convert.ToInt32(d1.DocumentId), // Include the unique identifier
                                 AssignedUser = new List<AssignedUser>(),
                                 DocumentType = d1.DocumentTypeId,
                                 DocSeries = d1.Serie,
                                 DocNumber = d1.Nro,
                                 DocRecep = d1.DocRecep,
                                 RutTaxId = d1.EmitingRUC,
                                 IssuedDate = d1.FchEmis,
                                 DueDate = d1.ExpireDate,
                                 CompanyName = d1.LegalName,
                                 ApprovalDate = drp.ExpiringApprovalDate,
                                 State = Convert.ToInt32(drp.Status),
                                 Claim = dc != null && dc.Claim == true,
                                 Comments = dc != null && dc.DocumentCommentId != 0,
                                 Pause = drp.Status.ToString() == "5",
                                 ApprovalType = null,
                                 ExpiredApproval = drp.ExpiredApproval
                             };

                 documents = query1.Union(query2)
                                 .GroupBy(x => x.DocumentId) // Group by the unique identifier
                                 .Select(g => g.First())
                                 .AsQueryable<AllDocumentDetails>();

These are working fine but issue is here
return documents.ToList()
only this code taking more than 2-3 minute
I want excute this query within second.

It's not ToList() that takes too long. The query is very inefficient and shows a severe misuse of Entity Framework. It's EF's job to generate JOINs from the relations between entities, not tables. If you have to write so many JOINs manually, something is very wrong

Profile the query, add some indexes if needed...

Looks to me that at least query2 hasn't been enumerated before and isn't yet executed. ToList will do that.

ToList() is not the problem. It's just executing/materializing the query you defined. It is your query that is slow. Without the ToList() you only build the query, but never execute it. That's called deferred execution and is an important concept to understand when using LINQ.

Note LINQ (including EF) uses deferred/lazily execution. Until you use a method which causes evaluation (e.g. .ToList() , FirstOrDefault(), etc..). The generated query has poor performance How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?

These are two quick queries not at all, they're very, very slow queries. That set assignedUser = acompDbContext.DocumentAssignationAssignedUsers executes another query for each result in the overall query. That's slow because it results in N extra queries. Even worse, that AssignedUser = allusers.Where(x ... executes even more queries for every result, resulting in N^2 queries. If the JOIN fileds aren't indexed you'll end up scanning entire tables N^2 times. The second query contains negated Any queries that can only produce results after evaluating all rows. That's extra delays

Either create a proper entity model and don't use JOINs, or create a stored procedure or view and map the results. Don't try to write complex SQL with LINQ.

I would stop, and rewrite the query into manageable sub queries. With intermediate queries, you get a better sense of what's going on. EF is NOT an SQL OPTIMIZER, but you have to think like one if you're not using STORED PROCS.

@GerrySchmitz and all
I appreciate all of your suggestions, but could someone maybe provide a sample code so I can see how to implement it?

Firsty, this is terrible practice:
var documentsSql = acompDbContext.Documents.ToList();

This is loading all documents into memory. You are then basing your queries off this in-memory list instead of letting EF build a query against the main table you are querying.
This line is Ok, but I would throw a Distinct on it:
var rutList = allCompanies.Select(c => c.Rut).Distinct().ToList();

I would suspect it could easily have duplicates, and the shorter a list, the better.
Now digging into the queries. First, we are going to focus on keeping these running in SQL, and doing away with the manual joining. EF works with navigation properties where entities have properties and collections to related entities which EF will build the necessary joins to run a query. The only time you should ever need to explicitly join tables is on loose associations. (relationships that are implied or shared between multiple tables and have no FK in the database) I also personally hate the LINQ format, so this example will be using fluent.
var query1 = acompDbContext.Documents
    .Select(x => new AllDocumentDetails
        {
            DocumentId = Convert.ToInt32(x.DocumentId), 
            AssignedUser = x.DocumentAssignations.Select(da => new AssignedUser { UserId = da.Id, Email = da.Email }).ToList(),
            DocumentType = x.DocumentTypeId,
            DocSeries = x.Serie,
            DocNumber = x.Nro,
            DocRecep = x.DocRecep,
            RutTaxId = x.EmitingRUC,
            IssuedDate = x.FchEmis,
            DueDate = x.ExpireDate,
            CompanyName = x.LegalName,
            ApprovalDate = x.DocumentReceivedProcess.ExpiringApprovalDate,
            State = Convert.ToInt32(x.DocumentReceivedProcess.Status),
            Claim = x.DocumentComment.Claim, // may need a null check.
            Comments = x.DocumentComment != null && x.DocumentComment.Id != 0,
            Pause = x.DocumentReceivedProcess.Status == 5,
            ApprovalType = Convert.ToInt32(x.DocumentAssignation.ApprovalType),
            ExpiredApproval = x.DocumentReceivedProcess.ExpiredApproval
        });

If you don't have a DocumentReceivedPricess or DocumentComment etc. on your Document entity, that is the first issue you should investigate and look to resolve if you want to use Entity Framework. These are the navigation properties that should be used to express the relationships between these related entities. Quite often the projects are set up with them, developers just aren't really aware on how/why they are used. They are not just for when you fetch an entity and related data back, they are also used in projection. (using Select)
You can test that initially by:
var results = query1.ToList();

... to ensure that works and returns the results you expect. From there you should be able to work out query2 similarly without using in-memory lists other than that rutList.
The resulting data should be:
var results = query1.Union(query2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.DocumentId)
    .Select(g => g.First());

Though I'm not sure why you only want the first document's grouped results.  That should get you headed in the right direction to sorting out these queries. Once the relationships and projections are working, if you still have performance issues then the next thing would be to look at further filtering (this still appears to be going through all documents when you don't seem to need all documents) and indexing within the database.

I appreciate your kind response. In fact, I went with the store procedure when I could not find a way to improve.
However, I appreciate your response very much and will be using this method with additional APIs.
Could you please give me some further advice and support, such as your social media handle so I may contact you?
